# Adding querystring variable breaks admin URLs

Tags: plugin-development, add-submenu-page

I've set up some admin pages using add_sub_menu() and whenever I add an additional querystring variable beyond the "page=" portion of the URL, I get a "Cannot load 'page-slug'." message.  When I remove the every variable the page loads correctly.  Here is my add menu code:

```
add_submenu_page(
  'plugin-slug',
  __( 'Post Types - Add', 'plugin-slug' ),
  null,
  'manage_options',
  'plugin-slug-posttypes-add',
  'display_admin_page_posttype_add'
);
```

If I browse to:

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin-slug-posttypes-add

it works fine.  But browsing to:

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin-slug-posttypes-add&post_type=sampletype

returns:

Cannot load content-toolkit-posttypes-add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're recieving this error because WordPress notices the `post_type` query argument and that `sampletype` is a valid registered post type, and thinks you're on an edit page. Try using a different query arg then `post_type`.

Note that `admin.php?page=plugin-slug-posttypes-add&post_type=thisisnotaposttype` and `admin.php?page=plugin-slug-posttypes-add&foo=bar` will both work fine.

Comment: I didn't realize using that specific variable name would affect it.  Thanks!